# Откуда взять более 256 различных символов?

Tags: c#

Мне для проверки программы нужно записать в файл более 256 различных символов. Записывать я умею, но откуда взять более 256 символов, и вообще, такое реально?

Comment: Если в кодировке unicode, где символы многобайтные - то запросто. https://unicode-table.com/ru/

Comment: @Mike, т.е. для потока байтов не подойдёт? где каждый байт может принять только 256 символов?

Comment: Вопрос лишь в том, что потом будет читать этот файл. Если читателя UTF-8 устроит то пишите в свой поток символы старше 0x80 двух и более байтными кодами

Answer (score 2):

У каждого символа есть свой номер. Если речь о наполнении файла случайными символами, то необходимо в цикле получать случайное число, а потом символ по этому числу как-то так:

```
((char)20).ToString();
```

конкретно тут получится символ с номером 20

Comment: Ответ правильный, но слишком короткий. Я бы предложил дописать про ASCII и про unicode.